# how to escape this properly in ActiveRecord in Rails 4.2 for use with intarray extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the intarray and need:

```
WHERE (tag_ids @> '{10001}')
```

but using this:

```
   query_obj= query_obj.where("tag_ids @> ?", mandatory_tag_id)
```

outputs:

```
WHERE (tag_ids @> '10001')
```

How can I output it correctly with the brackets?

#### edit #1

```
query_obj= query_obj.where("tag_ids @> {?}", mandatory_tag_id)
```

gives:

```
WHERE (tag_ids @> {'10001'})
```

and

```
query_obj= query_obj.where("tag_ids @> ?", "{#mandatory_tag_id}")
```

gives:

```
WHERE (tag_ids @> '{#mandatory_tag_id}')
```

Comment: What about `.where("tag_ids @> {?}", mandatory_tag_id)`?

Comment: why not : query_obj.where("tag_ids @> ?", "'{10001}'")

Comment: thx @Uzbekjon updated

Comment: thx @Boltz0r I updated with what I tried in edit #1

Comment: query_obj= query_obj.where("tag_ids @> '{?}'", mandatory_tag_id)

Comment: You might find the `array[...]` syntax easier to work with than the string `'{...}'` syntax; `array[1,2,3]` versus `'{1,2,3}'` (with an implicit `::int[]` cast) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query_obj= query_obj.where("tag_ids @> '{?}'", mandatory_tag_id)
```

It should work

Comment: yep - the problem I was having was that I had to have mandatory_tag_id as a string (ie mandatory_tag_id.to_i)